# I ran sudo chmod go-w /usr on my Mac - is this an issue?

Tags: macos, mac, chmod

So as the title suggested while troubleshooting a warning message, I mistakenly ran the following command in my Mac Terminal:

```
sudo chmod go-w /usr
```

Is this likely to cause me any problems and if so, can I undo it?

I also ran this to try and solve my original issue (which was on the wrong track altogether):

```
chmod 766 /usr/local
```

However this said it didn't have permission to run so hopefully that was harmless.

I will be much more careful with such commands in the future!

Comment: Try using the Fix Permissions operation in Disk Utility.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that anything in /usr needs to be writable, so this may be innocuous.

Comment: Only root would ever write to it, when installing new things, and it's unaffected by permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If the command did not have permission run then nothing was done and you will be fine.

Also giving the `/usr/local` folder sudo rights won’t do any harm.

Comment: `sudo` gives it permission.

Comment: Yes but not all commands some command need extra permission.

Comment: Changing things in system directories needs extra permission, and he gave it permission.

Comment: It could of but I have ran some commands with sudo and they did not run.

Comment: `/etc/sudoers` can be configured to restrict which commands different users can run. But the normal MacOS sudoers file allows admin users to execute anything. The file is rarely customized.

Comment: The only restriction is that even root can't get around [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection).

Comment: Even if it did get permission I don’t think the command was harmful.

Comment: True, I don't think anything in /usr need write permission.